# Drawing real coordinates

Tags: c++, plot, floating-point, coordinates, gdi

I've implemented a plotting class that is currently capable of handling integer values only. I would like to get advice about techniques/mechanisms in order to handle floating numbers. Library used is GDI.

Thanks,

Adi

Comment: GDI? ugh.. That's really old..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At some point, they need to be converted to integers to draw actual pixels.

Generally speaking, however, you do *not* want to just cast each float to int, and draw -- you'll almost certainly get a mess. Instead, you need/want to scale the floats, *then* round the scaled value to an integer. In most cases, you'll want to make the scaling factor variable so the user can zoom in and out as needed.

Another possibility is to let the hardware handle most of the work -- you could use OpenGL (for one example) to render your points, leaving them as floating point internally, and letting the driver/hardware handle issues like scaling and conversion to integers. This has a rather steep cost up-front (learning enough OpenGL to get it to do anything useful), but can have a fairly substantial payoff as well, such as fast, hardware-based rendering, and making it relatively easy to handle some things like scaling and (if you ever need it) being able to display 3D points as easily as 2D.

Edit:(mostly response to comment): Ultimately it comes down to this: the resolution of a screen is lower than the resolution of a floating point number. For example, a really high resolution screen *might* display 2048 pixels horizontally -- that's 11 bits of resolution. Even a single precision floating point number has around 24 bits of precision. No matter how you do it, reducing 24-bit resolution to 12-bit resolution is going to lose something -- usually a *lot*.

That's why you pretty nearly *have* to make your scaling factor variable -- so the user can choose whether to zoom out and see the whole picture with reduced resolution, or zoom in to see a small part at high resolution.

Since sub-pixel resolution was mentioned: it does help, but only a *little*. It's not going to resolve a thousand different items that map to a single pixel.

Comment: Cool this is a good answer. Yes, I could use DirectDraw as i have some experience with it but if i wanted to scale it manually how would you do it on a value for example 35.78?

If i scale it with a scaling factor 1.2 that would be 35.78*1.2=42.936 so let's say i would round it to 43. But what happens when i want to scale value 35.8? That with the same scaling factor gives again 43. What about a resolution?

Thanks

Comment: @Adi: If you want to draw with a subpixel resolution use OpenGL/D3D with anti-aliasing, or WPF or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

What do these `float` values represent? I will assume they are some co-ordinates. You will need to know two things:

- The source resolution (i.e. the dpi at which these co-ordinates are drawn)
- The range that you need to address

After that, this becomes a problem of scaling the points to suitable integer co-ordinates (based on your screen-resolution).

Edit: A simple formula will be:

> `X(dst) = X(src) * DPI(dst) / DPI(src)`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to convert them to integers and then pass them to functions like `MoveTo()` and `LineTo()`.

Answer (score 0):

Scale.  For example, multiply all the integral values by 10.  Multiply the floating point values by 10.0 and then truncate or round (your choice).  Now plot as normal.

This will give you extra precision in your graphing.  Just remember the scale factor when you look at the picture.

Otherwise convert the floats to int before plotting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use GDI+ instead GDI, it has functions that are using float coordinates.